Understanding よりも先んじる
I am unsure about the meaning of コンシューマーよりも先んじていました here.

「美少女」というジャンルに関しては最初から今までずっとパソコンゲームがコンシューマーよりも先んじていました。

I don't think it means "to be ahead of consumers." What is the function of より here? Does 先んじる means to be a leading choice?

This 「コンシューマー」 is 「コンシューマーゲーム」, which is basically console games, and in this context compared to 「パソコンゲーム」. So your reading for for 先んじる is correct.  "As for the genre, games played on PC have always been ahead of console games".
Games played on home video game consoles (such as PlayStations, Xbox, Nintendo Switch, etc), in contrast to PC, smartphones, or those large machines in amusement arcades, are commonly referred to as コンシューマーゲーム, and those consoles are sometimes classified as コンシューマー（ゲーム）機.  This is Wasei-eigo: its basic idea is probably that these consoles are intended for individual consumers, rather than businesses.

Interesting read on 電ファミニコゲーマー: 「コンシューマー」？ 「コンソール」？ それとも……？ 「家庭用ゲーム機」を指す言葉のちょっとややこしい歴史を徹底的に調べてみた (Perhaps full-page ads may get in the way, click 「広告をスキップ」 on top)
jawp article 「コンシューマーゲーム」 has some descriptions

